# The kippah and dina d'malchuta dina

Tags: kippa-yarmulka, dina-dmalchusa-dina

If the military forces a Jewish member to remove his kippah because they do not allow head covering, must he comply under dina d'malchuta dina or not?  On the one hand, head covering in Judaism is a matter of custom, not law.  On the other hand, the rule does seem arbitrary.  I know there were cases reported in the press.  But what does the halacha say?

(My take from the discussion below: If the government forces you to remove your kippah or else, and your arguments don't sway them, you must remove it under dina d'malchuta dina.  Someone correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: It seems somewhat comparable to the color of shoelaces for which  you are supposed to give up your life ([Sanhedrin 74b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=74b&format=pdf))

Comment: A head covering is matter of "custom, not law"? I guess you haven't seen the Responsa of the Tzemach Tzedek.

Comment: I think they allow hats. And, some are black, too. Point is - I think there's a relatively easy work-around to the kippa problem in the U.S. military.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman_v._Weinberger

Comment: This question does not appear to be relevant anymore. Army Times has an article [New Army policy OKs soldiers to wear hijabs, turbans and religious beards By: Meghann Myers January 5, 2017](https://www.armytimes.com/news/your-army/2017/01/05/new-army-policy-oks-soldiers-to-wear-hijabs-turbans-and-religious-beards/). As a result, the halacha would appear to be that the soldier would have to fill out the appropriate paperwork. Note that when the regulations require an army uniform head covering, the soldier would be required to wear it.

Comment: @ba That’s only true in a time of persecution. Seemingly a draft to the army doesn’t qualify.

Comment: @b a  But Rava says there when the purpose is not harass you or force you to sin, you may transgress in public (ten Jews) to save your life.

Comment: I know the problem is solved for the US military.  But what about the general case?  Must you refuse to remove the kippah or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wearing a kippa at work](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/wearing-a-kippa-at-work). Why should it make a difference what the job is - if it’s allowed, it’s allowed. You don’t even need to get into Dina d’malchusa.

Comment: Another point may be what the Dina Demalchusa actually is. For example, the difference between France and the United States. The way the secular law is actually written and enforced could make a difference in how the halacha views it.

Answer (score 1):

As is found at [The Virtual Jewish Library on the subject of Dina de Malkhuta Dina](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/dina-de-malkhuta-dina), in the section discussing the scope of the laws included in Dina de Malkhuta Dina it quotes the Tashbetz, part 1 No.158 which says:

> (1) *ISSUR ("religious prohibitions") AND MONETARY LAW. All agree that the principle does not apply to religious or ritual observances (issur ve-hetter). This was so certain that it was not particularly stressed and is mentioned only in a few sources (Tashbeẓ, pt. 1, no. 158).

So the question revolves around whether wearing a kippah (a head covering) is a religious or ritual observance subject to issur v'hetter.

It is explained in the [Piskei Dinim of the Tzemach Tzedek, Vol.1, pp 1-2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30499&st=&pgnum=9), that the kippah, as contrasted to the outer hat, which many wear over the kippah when going into public, is required by ritual law. He explains that those places which mention a Jewish man's head being uncovered are referring to the outer hat, which is a *Middah Chassidut*, not the kippah.

In that context, one would not be required to comply under the principle of Dina de Malchuta Dina.

Comment: How come it took until the 19th century for someone to say that wearing a kippah is a requirement of Jewish law rather than custom?